# Show that $\mathbb Z_6/([3]) \simeq \mathbb Z_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I need to show that 
$$\mathbb Z_6/([3]) \simeq \mathbb Z_3$$
How would I use the first isomorphism theorem to show this?

Comment: Can you define group (ring?) homomorphism $\Bbb Z_6\to\Bbb Z_3$ that will be surjective?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Consider the homomorphism:
\begin{align}
\mathbf Z/6\mathbf Z &\longmapsto \mathbf Z/3\mathbf Z \\
n+6\mathbf Z&\longmapsto n+3\mathbf Z
\end{align}
Show it is well defined. What is its kernel?